# Call OpenJson from C# without a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Considering that openjson function does not depend on any tables on a databse wondering if there is a way to call openJson function of tsql from C# without having an actutal database/server

Comment: No. You can't run T-SQL without a connection, you need an instance to run the query.

Comment: In C# you typically would have no need for `OPENJSON` to begin with, as there are packages like Json.NET to offer comparable functionality with much more flexibility.

Comment: Or even `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: If you really needed this you could use a LocalDB installation, and connect to `master`. But why you would do this is beyond me: just use JSON.Net or System.Text.Json